# Hybris create permission for extended item type

Tags: permissions, sap-commerce-cloud

The case we are dealing with: We have an item type A which is extended from B. Now we have a user group UG. They have to be able to create type A items in the BO, but not type Bs. Therefor we restricted them in item type level to have the permission to create item type A, but not item type B. These items have their own defined place in the tree and are listed in our Backoffice, so they have their own listveiw section. In this section if we would like to create a new A or B item, there is the + sign for it. The problem is, that the UG doesn't even able to click on the + sign even if they have permission to create type A.
What do we miss here?

Comment: Does the user have UG only, or does it also have other usergroups? I'm assuming that you have explicitly defined `+`create access to A and `-` create access to B.

Comment: The user has only their inherited groups. Yes, we have explicitly defined those accesses. We assumed that the child's access will override the parent's.